# Why does Pymodbus change baudrate when running on linux without requesting a baudrate change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymodbus

I have python3 program that acts as a Modbus Master. I start a ModbusSerialClient and then proceed to read register from the slave. This is working fine on Windows. The issue is that on Ubuntu I am seeing that the ModbusSerialClient keeps changing the baudrate which makes the communication inconsistent.

I start the communication with:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
...
try:
            self.client = ModbusClient(
                method = 'rtu'
                ,port= self.port
                ,baudrate=int(115200)
                ,parity = 'N'
                ,stopbits=1
                ,bytesize=8
                ,timeout=3
                ,RetryOnEmpty = True
                ,RetryOnInvalid = True
            )
            self.connection = self.client.connect()
            # Some delay may be necessary between connect and first transmission
            time.sleep(2)
```

Where `self.port = "COM_X"` in Windows and `self.port = "/dev/ttyS1"` in Linux

And then I read the registers using:

```
rr = self.client.read_holding_registers(register_addr,register_block,unit=MODBUS_CONFIG_ID)
if(rr.isError()):
   logger.debug(rr)
else:
   # Proceed with the processing
```

The error I log in some ocasions is:

```
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
```

I have verified the baudrate change physically measuring the signals.
I have verified that with a command line tools like `cu` the baudrate remains consistent.

The verions I am using are:

- pymodbus `3.1.0` (error also present with `2.5.3`)
- pyserial `3.5`
- python `3.8.10`
- kubuntu `22.04` (same behaviour with ubuntu)

Comment: Hello Ricard, where are you running your client? Is it a Raspberry Pi or similar?

Comment: It is an industriual grade touch panel PC with an intel J1900 CPU

Comment: just in case, check if the serial port you are trying to use is spiting kernel messages from time to time. I think the server images of Ubuntu and/or Kubuntu have the console set up by default.

Comment: I have checked with 'dmesg' and there are no error messages

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I don't mean you are getting any error messages but some Linux systems sometimes are set up to write kernel debug messages and other info to a serial port. If that's your case you might see very strange things happening like the port working perfectly fine and suddenly printing weird stuff. You might want to take a look at your [kernel parameters](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html). Just do a `dmesg | grep command` and see if you can find something like `console=ttyS1` or whereabouts.

Comment: What hardware are you using for the serial port. Motherboard? PCI card? Virtual?

Comment: Seems like a SSD failure was causing high CPU usage which may have caused the serial communication to misbehave. Waiting for a new hw to verify

Comment: The issue was confirmed to be caused by spike in the CPU caused by the dead SSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was confirmed to be caused by spike in the CPU caused by the dead SSD.